# Creating HTML elements for javascript testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, enzyme

So i have a particular problem, inside my react component i used commands like these:

```
document.getElementById('modalsContainer').appendChild(recognitionProfileZoom);
document.getElementById('modalsContainer').appendChild(categoryZoom);
```

and:

```
document.getElementById('cddoccategoryzoom').value;
```

But these elements that were specified by ID don't exist in my component.
How would one go about creating these objects on the tests?

The code below would use these elements but it fails because they don't exist(**the hideModal function utilizes the document.append from before**)

```
describe("CaptureProfileModal functions tests", function() {

it('Should hide the modal', function() {
    var wrapper, instance;

    wrapper = mount(
        <CaptureProfileModal
            gridAction={1}
            captureSettingCode={15}
            fields={mockedFields}/>
    );

    wrapper.setState({
        showModal: true
    });

    instance = wrapper.component.getInstance();
    instance.hideModal();
});
```

Comment: For starters all ID's are lowercase, you shouldn't use uppercase in an ID if you want it to work with all browsers.  Also get use to getting the element and checking the return of getElementByID, do not assume it will succeed.

Comment: HTML element IDs are [case-sensitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).  All browsers since IE8 support case-sensitive strings in `getElementById`.

Comment: why your don't just mock them ?

Comment: how can I mock a DOM element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Creating DOM elements in your enzyme tests:**

So guys, to create **DOM** elements in your test, it's actually really simple and you type it just as you would in vanilla javascript, with the global keyword:

```
it('Should hide the modal', function() {
        var wrapper, instance;
        var modalsContainer = global.document.createElement('div');
        var recognitionProfileZoom = global.document.createElement('div');
        var categoryZoom = global.document.createElement('div');

        modalsContainer.id = 'modalsContainer';
        recognitionProfileZoom.id = 'recognitionProfileZoom';
        categoryZoom.id = 'categoryZoom';
        global.document.body.appendChild(modalsContainer);
        global.document.body.appendChild(recognitionProfileZoom);
        global.document.body.appendChild(categoryZoom);
```

After this is done you can expect values, and use the DOM elements normally.