# Why does my enzyme snapshot test of React fail on a document.getElementById() call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, snapshot, enzyme

I am trying to render a Snapshot test of a nested React component, but the test code fails to handle a document.getElementById() request. The component's relevant code section is here:

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let scrollbarWidth = appScrollbarWidth();
    let headerWrapper = document.getElementById(this.headerWrapperId);
    headerWrapper.style.right = scrollbarWidth +"px";
    document.body.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:" + scrollbarWidth * 0.8 + "px;");
  };
```

The unit test code (using enzyme) is here:

```
describe("GridRows Snapshot", () => {
  it("renders a Snapshot without error", () => {
    const component = mount( 
      <GridRows wrapperId = {"dummyId"}
       headerWrapperId = {"dummyheaderId"}
       dataWrapperId = { "dummydataId"}
       dataArray = {rowDefsArray}
       columnClassNameAddOn = {"grid-layout-8cols"}
      />
    );
    expect(component.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

When I run the test, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
```

referring to this line:

```
headerWrapper.style.right = scrollbarWidth +"px";
```

As a workaround, I bypass the failing code like this, which allows the 
snapshot to continue with only a cosmetic change, and does not change the real output.

```
  componentDidMount = () => {
    let scrollbarWidth = appScrollbarWidth();
    let headerWrapper = document.getElementById(this.headerWrapperId);

    if (headerWrapper) {
       headerWrapper.style.right = scrollbarWidth +"px";
    }

    document.body.setAttribute("style", "padding-left:" + scrollbarWidth * 0.8 + "px;");
  };
```

Am I missing something to make this work without the fix?

Comment: where are you running the tests (browser/js-dom) and what test runner are you using

Comment: You might need to create the element in your test.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46057037/creating-dom-elements-for-javascript-testing) answer

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to mock the `document` for your tests.

In your global test setup file, add this:

`global.window = document.defaultView`

And then in the individual test you can stub different properties or functions on the global mocked document in a `beforeEach`

eg: `document.getElementById = () => {}`

Hope this helps

Comment: You are right, although there's not enough info here for me to understand the code required. I did figure it out using the link suggested by EliaMelfior above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised snapshot unit test, where I create DOM elements for the test

```
describe("GridContainer Snapshot", () => {
  it("renders a Snapshot without error", () => {
    const headerWrapperId = "PlanOverallResultsgrid1-header-wrapper"
    const headerWrapper = global.document.createElement("div")
    headerWrapper.id = headerWrapperId
    global.document.body.appendChild(headerWrapper)
    const component = mount(
      <GridContainer
        tab_key={1}
        id={"PlanOverallResultsgrid1"}
        chart_name={chart_name}
        data_object={chartcontent}
      />
    )
    expect(component.getElements()).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
})
```

I guess I don't understand Enzyme's mount method. I thought that mount rendered all the DOM. The component that needed the document.getElementById() to work was a child component of the GridContainer which renders the DIVs hosting the child, including the one the child wants to find. So why is the mocking required?